# SpringBoot 1.3.0 support hibernate 5?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-5.x

I'm a little confused about SpringBoot's (1.3.0) support of Hibernate5.  The reference lists a dependency on hibernate 4.3.11.Final but it also lists a dependency on SpringFramework 4.2.3 which includes Hibernate5 support.

Is it just a matter of adding the extra Hibernate5 dependencies to override what Boot bundles?  Can someone please clarify for me?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use either Hibernate 4.3 or Hibernate 5.0 with Spring Boot 1.3. As you've observed, Hibernate 4.3.x is the default version.

To use Hibernate 5.0 you should override the `hibernate.version` property in Spring Boot's dependency management. Assuming that you're using Maven:

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.5.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

When using Hibernate 5.0, the one big difference from using Hibernate 4.3.x is that you'll lose Spring Boot's custom naming strategy. Due to a breaking change made in Hibernate 5.0, you'll see a warning like this logged at startup:

```
2015-12-07 10:04:56.911  WARN 81371 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000006: Attempted to specify unsupported NamingStrategy via setting [hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy]; NamingStrategy has been removed in favor of the split ImplicitNamingStrategy and PhysicalNamingStrategy; use [hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy] or [hibernate.physical_naming_strategy], respectively, instead.
```

If you dislike Hibernate 5's defaults, you can specify a custom implicit or physical naming strategy in Spring Boot's `application.properties` using the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` properties respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, however excuse my ignorance, could you elaborate on how I can migrate to hibernate 5 without breaking anything that already exists? Is there a naming strategy that substitutes the one we're currently using `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy`? Or maybe its a better decision to hold back on Hibernate 5 at the moment until Spring boot officially migrates?

Answer (score 6):

*Update July 2016*: With the release of Spring Boot 1.4.0 the default [Hibernate 5 is used as the default JPA persistence provider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#hibernate-5).

---

There is a [ticket about migrating to Hibernate 5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2763) for some time now - it seems the main setback is some name strategy incompatibility. Asof now, the ticket is currently scheduled for **1.4.0**

Comment: 1.4.0 is now released with Hibernate 5 being the default JPA persistence provider. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys! after many trials, this solution worked for me like a charm! I implemented custom strategy and set them in application.yml as shown below:

```
   jpa:
    database: MYSQL
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    properties:
        hibernate:
            implicit_naming_strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
            physical_naming_strategy: com.quicken.ups.entities.utils.DBFieldNamingStrategy
```

Comment: Where could i find the code for : com.quicken.ups.entities.utils.DBFieldNamingStrategy ?